# when I'm rendering the image, the render doesn't work on the camera view

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, camera, image

I just started using blander and when I'm rendering the image, the render doesn't work on the camera view... I've looked all over the web for the solution and couldn't find anything!

Thanks to anyone who helps :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender's Stack Exchange :). Please try to better describe what is exactly happening. Your rendered image doesn't match your camera view? You can also add some Images or your [Blendfile](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)